# JPA Criteria query: Join on or clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

Let's assume we have a few tables in SQL.

Table A, B, C and D.

Table B and C is an extension of D, but is made as a single table.

Table A has two references to D through b_uid and c_uid.

Suppose I want to do a join from A to D. That is possible with

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN D ON
    D.uid = A.b_uid
    OR
    D.uid = A.c_uid
```

How do I express this in a JPA Criteria Query?

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
Join<A, D> dJoin = root.join(D.class).on("b_uid").or("c_uid");
```

I'm using the Jarkarta persistence api version 2.2.3